# dynamodb get binary from item

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, boto3

i get a item from dynamo that have a binary key

```
'privateKey': {'B': Binary(b'MIHuAgEAMBAGByqGSM49AgEGBSuBBAAjBIHWMIHTAgEBBEIAbUQtIiLfXVNPQVlbi//CTJ5AVb52j8irzsjME4C+ij7Y34NxIdmG3bfhsYyho3FztDFwslc9KdK+ohIazuJvBK2hgYkDgYYABAComfJVVDCvvEooZg+K6HRHwYmYUTCF4AULevxHySb/psO95Oqyhx7DdBx3MdBQ8KgDihWH3D/t70JFhl3o09ZirwFxazjEh0Sxulgidr5rpq+1JESxfuADYhb6P4zgK6teWD96VtizxDguPzcdEo2sWiuOWR83w3vHAH3ZwwledjiWDg==')
```

when i try pass to base 64

```
prikey  = KeyGenerator().getPrivateKeyDeode(result["privateKey"]["B"])
```

launch the next error

TypeError","errorMessage":"argument should be a bytes-like object or ASCII string, not 'Binary'"

Comment: and this: `result["privateKey"]["B"].decode()`?

Comment: @Marcin launch this error  'Binary' object has no attribute 'decode'

Answer (score 0):

binary have the attribute value, and you get the the binary, like this.

```
result["privateKey"]["B"].value
```